# Is there a multiplatform component for In App Purchase?

Tags: react-native

I just need a way to let people to buy virtual goods ( in subscription too ).

This works only for Ios: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils

This works only for Android: https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing

This seems that doens't work anymore: https://github.com/satya164/react-native-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Try use [react-native-iap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap).

This one supports both platforms (ios and android)